# Freezing and spike in processor usage when changing brightness

Tags: release-juno, system, pantheon

I know I'm using an old entry level laptop (specs in the end), but I'm having problems with instability with Elementary OS that I never had with Gnome Shell and lighter DEs like MATE with Compiz, whenever I change brightness (it always happens, the exception being change brightness again a few seconds after doing it the last time), and sometimes even starting to type, opening the menu or changing volume causes a freeze on the system (I can move the mouse but can't do anything), most of the time it freezes for like 1-2 seconds but sometimes it can take up to 10 seconds for the system to recover. I checked system monitor and whenever I change brightness, I have a spike on processor usage up to 100% in just one thread. I thought it might be due to swapping but it happens even when there is below 1GB of RAM usage and no swapping.

**Specs:**
Intel Core i3-3217U (2C4T, 1.8GHz), 32GB SSD where the system is installed + HDD for data, 4GB 1600MHz DDR3 RAM, Intel HD 4000 IvyBridge graphics. Temperatures are fine and the processor usage is usually pretty low, except when viewing videos on Youtube or having constant swapping.

Comment: Can you please add the make and model of the laptop? There is a similar issue affecting some Dell and HP laptops (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/847001)

Comment: It is a HP Sleekbook/Ultrabook 14 (the name depends on the country sold, it is Sleekbook in the US). It seems to be the same problem but none of the workarounds shown there worked here. I noticed the problem occur with the play/pause key too, but only if anything is being played (then it occurs the same CPU spike until the balloon shows up showing that nothing is playing), if there is a song being played it only pauses without any hiccup. It didn't happen on Pop OS 19.10 (which is based on Ubuntu)

Comment: the biggest differences between elementary OS 5.0 and Pop_OS 19.10 are the DE and kernel (Pantheon vs Gnome and 4.15 vs 5.3). Would you be willing to try a kernel upgrade, to see if the problem has been fixed in a newer version?

Comment: I'm using HWE kernel (5.0), the problem was present on 4.15 too.